# "Label not found" error in code coverage with jstestdriver

Tags: javascript, js-test-driver

I have some javascript code with do while outer loop and switch inner loop, inner switch loop contains break outerloop. below is simplified version of code.
While generating code coverage with jstestdriver coverage plugin, I am getting error "Label not found" at line "break loop1".

```
    var a = 2;
    var c = 5;
    loop1:
        do {
            switch (c) {
            case 1 :
                break;
            default :
                break loop1;
            }
            a--;
        } while (a !=0);
```

Any help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/issues/detail?id=387) in the JsTestDriver coverage plugin. Until fixed, the **solution** would be to **refactor** your code **to not use labels** to break loops.

The code coverage plugin inserts statements on each line to record which lines have been executed, even between the label and the `do` statement. This detaches them from each other.

The code executed with coverage enabled would look something like this:

```
// ...
LCOV_1f[3]++; loop1:
    LCOV_1f[4]++; do {
        // ...
    } while (a !=0);
```